# Issue with Wix Web application Setup into IIS virtual directory

Tags: iis, wix

I trying to install web application into virtual directory i.e. "c:\Inetpub\XYZ". But it is installing into "D:\XYZ" or Mysource directory is "D:\". Can any body help me how to install into website location (XYZ) in IIS virtual directory("C:\Inetpub\XYZ").

```
    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="XYZ"> 


      <Component Id="VirtualDirectoryComponent" Guid="DED95D72-52AE-4258-9D50-687E65449F95">
        <CreateFolder />


        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="My.VirtualDir" Alias="[WEB_APP_NAME]" Directory="INSTALLDIR"  WebApplication="" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
          <iis:WebApplication Id="Application" Name="[WEB_APP_NAME]" />
          <iis:WebDirProperties Id="WebSite_Properties" AnonymousAccess="yes" WindowsAuthentication="no" DefaultDocuments="Default.aspx" Script="yes"
                               Read="yes" />
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>


      </Component>

</Directory>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the directory with following

```
Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
<!-- Install into the ISS root directory -->
<Directory Id="IISROOT" Name='WebDir'>
<!-- Here's this installers install location. -->
<Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='XYZ'></Directory>
</Directory>
```